# Replace ASCII characters in a string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am removing HTML tags from this data saved with these tags using the following

```
var Summary = HtmlString.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi,'');
```

the above statement does replace most of the TAGS except `&#8226; ,  &#183; ,  &#8216; ,  &nbsp;` etc.

I am trying to figure out JavaScript replace function to find all that start with `&#` and ends on semicolon ;

Any help will be appreciated

var Summary = HtmlString.replace(/</?[^>]+>/gi,'');

Comment: Not sure what you're doing, but I hope you're aware that you can get `element.textContent` which will return the raw text content without tags.

Comment: The regexp `/&.+?;/` will match any HTML entity strings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Below is how data is saved in SQL table. I need to extract just plain text. I dont know why vendor is saving free text data in HTML format. I have the flexibility to use JavaScript in the vendor application to create an interface CSV file. I am going to try the regx solution above but wanted to explain the input source.

record 1
<p style="margin-left:0in;margin-right:0in;font-size:11.0pt;margin-top:0in;line-height:107%;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">That the quick brown fox jumped over the lazdy dog. Mary's dog barks a lot.<span>&#160;&#160; </span></p>